# ffmpeg multi quality conversion?

Tags: ffmpeg

is there any way in a one line of command i convert mp4 file to ts ,but with 3 different quality as output files ? for example 480p 720p 1080p ?

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

See here, specifically "Same filtering for all outputs":

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Creating%20multiple%20outputs

Comment: can i ask you to write such a code for me , i'm not very familiar with coding